# EncryprPad cannot detect USB drive

Tags: usb-drive, filemanager

I cannot see use my USB device with EncryptPad's file browser. No problem with Ubuntu and all other apps. Only this app refuses to acknowledge the presence of USB flash pen

Comment: Did you compile it yourself or downloaded binaries? I compile encryptpad myself and I have the USB drive. Could you tell me where from you took the binaries? I might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. EncryptPad (QT to be precise) normally integrates with the native file manager to browse files through the GTK2 platform theme plugin. However, this Qt version (Qt5.7) has a known issue:

GTK2 plugin libqgtk2.so is missing from the installation because the Qt team have moved to GTK3 and they could not package GTK3 in 5.7.
The bug has been reported [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52259)

Quote from the link above:

> This is really an issue - it took some time to figure out why the
>   native file dialog is not shown anymore with Qt 5.7 under Linux Mint
>   17.3. I suggest to give others an official hint about this.

There are a few options:

1. Wait until Qt 5.8 in which the problem should be fixed.
2. Use AppImage
3. Mount or link the USB drive directory to a more convenient place where it could be opened from the limited Qt file manager.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have now deleted the useless program. I can live without it

Comment: You don't use it anymore. It's fine. I would still appreciate if you told me what your environment was. I will create a ticket so it gets fixed in the future. Ubuntu flavor, version (I assume it was Ubuntu)?

Comment: Sorry I missed your earlier question. I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been raised [here](https://github.com/evpo/EncryptPad/issues/46)